# Why smallScreens=false prevents app from being installed on Pixel 3 (from Google Play)?

Tags: android

I added this to my manifest, to prevent my app being installed on small screens:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I can't install the app anywhere anymore, including on my Pixel 3 (which AFAIU should be large screen). I'm quite sure that this element is the reason. If I remove `supports-screens`, it can be installed. I've not tried yet with all 4 attributes set to `true`.

Note: Only affects Play Store install (internal/alpha/etc). It runs normally when installed from AS/directly.